# wp-admin and wp-includes keep coming back

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel, whm

There is a strange issue happening after I updated to wordpress 4.3. First of all I got no access to wp-admin because it went into a loop and the public_html changed permissions to 750 from 755. I tried removing via cpanel the entire public_html folder but it keeps coming back on reload with the folders wp-admin and wp-includes inside it along with all the other files. So I renamed the public_html folder to public_html123456 and re-created the public_html folder, after re-uploaded the site to the public_html folder. No more errors, but this happened to all sites that I updated to 4.3. Also want to mention that the public_html123456 still can't be deleted, files re-appearing. Want to mention that I am using File Manager from Cpanel. Have anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: You probably don't have the proper file permissions to remove public_html on your server, so you *think* you're removing it, but it's not actually being removed.

Comment: @cale_b Tied with normal cpanel password and with root password and still same issue.

Comment: You're missing my point: I don't think it will matter *what* credentials you use, you *do not have* permission to delete the public_html folder.  That's a core part of most web host servers, and you almost certainly are not permitted to remove it.

Comment: @cale_b but I should be able to remove the contents inside the public_html folder right? Every file and folder from the public_html folder except the wp-admin and wp-includes folder gets removed. And when I tried to remove wp-admin or wp-includes or both they re-appear.

Comment: Ok, very odd I managed to remove the directories but via FTP, File manager from CPanel did not work. I am using latest version of cpanel and WHM.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.
Here is the solution:
First enable hidden files by cliking of setting icon then check "Show hidden files"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeNQU.png)

Now delete only wp-admind and wp-content
they will be deleted.